# For AltThree/Locker package laravel how to define Redis connection?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, redis, locking, predis

https://github.com/AltThree/Locker After instaling this package in laravel a file called `locker.php` is being created under the `config` directory.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

/*
 * This file is part of Alt Three Locker.
 *
 * (c) Alt Three Services Limited
 *
 * For the full copyright and license information, please view the LICENSE
 * file that was distributed with this source code.
 */

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Connection
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This defines the redis connection to use when acquiring locks.
    |
    */

    'connection' => null,

];
```

**My question is that how can I define the Redis connection here? Any help would be appreciated.**

Answer (score 1):

It seems package using that connection name to create a `Illuminate\Cache\RedisStore` https://github.com/AltThree/Locker/blob/5204370e6ad31f434c75b14ed627acfbe688b3bd/src/LockerServiceProvider.php#L72-L94

`RedisStore` accept connection name as a string: https://laravel.com/api/8.x///Illuminate/Cache/RedisStore.html

I think you need to use a connection name defined in your `config/database.php` and it is `redis` by default.

Comment: I Will let you know if it works or not.